# pre fill custom fields with DocuSign iOS Native SDK

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am running Swift sample from https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk.

I want to pre-fill a **Custom field(Data Label - "fullNameLabel")** that i have assigned to a field in my template/document.
I have tried sending `let dict = ["fullNameLabel":"tom wood"]` and `let dict = ["tabLabel":"fullNameLabel","value":"tom wood"]` in **DSMEnvelopeDefaults** object's **tabValueDefaults** property and calling

```
- (void)presentSendTemplateControllerWithTemplateWithId:(NSString *)templateId
                                   envelopeDefaults:(DSMEnvelopeDefaults *)envelopeDefaults
                                        pdfToInsert:(NSData *)pdfToInsert
                                   insertAtPosition:(DSMDocumentInsertAtPosition)insertAtPosition
                                        signingMode:(DSMSigningMode)signingMode
                               presentingController:(UIViewController *)presentingController
                                           animated:(BOOL)animated
                                         completion:(void(^)(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error))completion;
```

But when the document loads the field does not get pre-populated. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a few reasons for not seeing the fields pre-populated. Most likely,  the template you are using doesn't have a text tab with `tabLabel` = `"fullNameLabel"`. Ensure this by cross-checking the `tabLabel` on the template. The sample template has a label defined as `"Text FullName"` in [Guide: Using Envelope Defaults](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/blob/release/2.2/Using-Envelope-Defaults.md). Link to [template json](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/blob/release/2.2/support-files/Home_insurance_claim_adjuster_template.json) with `"Text FullName"` tabLabel.

`let dict = ["fullNameLabel":"tom wood"]` --> This should work, as long as you're setting both `recipientDefaults` and `tabDefaults`.

```
let envelopeDefaults = DSMEnvelopeDefaults()
// Set the tab default values
envelopeDefaults.tabValueDefaults = tabData 
// Also set recipient default (required for tab defaults)
envelopeDefaults.recipientDefaults = recipientDefault
```

`let dict = ["tabLabel":"fullNameLabel","value":"tom wood"]` --> 
  This `Dictionary<String, String>` won't work as it expects the format to be in `tabLabel`:`defaultValue`  pair.

For extra details and step by step guide, take a look at [Using Envelope Defaults](https://github.com/docusign/native-ios-sdk/blob/release/2.2/Using-Envelope-Defaults.md).